# How do I insert 10000 values into Oracle and keep them in the right order?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to insert 10000 values into Oracle from C# and am using the code below. It is VERY important that the order of the values in the array that I pass in are maintained in Oracle, however every time I run this the order of the values changes. What can I change to stop the order changing, or is there a completely different approach that I can use to insert 10000 values in a set order that can be retrieved easily?

The datalist is an array of type double and size 10000.

```
var oc = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
oc.Open();
var transaction = oc.BeginTransaction();
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("",oc);
command.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO DEMO (DISTRIBUTIONSLICES) values (:DISTRIBUTIONSLICES)");

OracleParameter distributionslices = new OracleParameter("DISTRIBUTIONSLICES",OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);

distributionslices.Value = datalist;

command.Parameters.Add(distributionslices);
command.ArrayBindCount = 10000;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a sequence in database(lets name it seq).
- Alter table add (seq_id number);
- INSERT INTO DEMO (DISTRIBUTIONSLICES, seq_id) values
  (:DISTRIBUTIONSLICES, seq.nextval())
- select in this way:

  Select * 
  from demo
  order by seq_id

Answer (score 7):

Paradigm error: Rows in a SQL database table don't, in general, have an order you can rely on.

If you want to be able to retrieve rows in a known order, you need to do something explicit to make that happen, such as adding an extra column of unique integers which defines the order you want.

You can then retrieve your rows with ORDER BY on your ordering column, and it will give you the rows in the order you want.